# Is it possible that there is a third class of fermions?

Tags: particle-physics, fermions, beyond-the-standard-model, elementary-particles

There exist six types of quarks, and six types of leptons, both divided in three generations.
Could there be some other new class of exactly six particles, similar to these, but with properties such that they haven't been discovered yet?

For example, they may require energies beyond what is achievable on our current technology, or they may not interact strongly or electromagnetically, thus being nearly invisible to detectors.

Comment: You might be interested to read about Supersymmetey

Comment: @RC_23 Sfermions come in groups of six but I guess they wouldn't be similar to normal fermions; and sbosons, having spin-1/2, do not come in a pack of six.

Comment: Why "exactly six"? Are you proposing a vague gauge anomaly cancellation scheme? Of course there may be heavier particles at inaccessible energies, and new interactions. That is why HEP is exploring as high energies as possible.

Comment: There's probably a reasonable answer to be written explaining anomaly cancellation in electroweak theory, but I am far from qualified to write it.